# Need simulator of 8051 with a 'c' compiler?

Tags: hardware, microcontroller, simulator, 8051

Is there any simulator of 8051 which comes with 'c' compiler so that i can compile our c code and able to view the result ?

Answer (score 2):

sdcc is a commonly used C compiler for the 8051 and googling 8051 simulator results in several simulator tools.

Answer (score 2):

For a good c compiler use [Keil C51](https://www.keil.com/download/product/). It is an excellent compiler which a huge device database to select from!

You can use keil to generate a Hex file (in the Intel hex file format). You can then load the hex file into [Edsim](http://www.edsim51.com/) to simulate your design and see the output!

Answer (score 0):

one of the best complier+simulator is **keil C51**.Just download it use trial version that is sufficient for beginner programming .It support both assembly language as well as embedded C.
So it is best for you .Again it having debugger which is used for checking your code in machine level.

Another simulator is there for you **ISIS professional** which is best among all the  simulator I used till date.It provide circuit simulator which having a lot of peripheral library for easy design of circuit.And you can load your code to this for see the real time behavior of your circuit with your code .Just **google** it to find out more about ISIS professional.Again free version is sufficient for starting Embedded C.It also support virtual devices like volt meter,oscilloscope,signal generator....

So I think this is best for starting embedded study.But use **keil debugger** for better knowing behavior of your code in machine level.